# How to list all ratings received by user

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables

draws users and ratings

users contains the user_id, draws contains an id for the draw and the user_id who is the owner of that draw, in the ratings table i save the user that gives the rating, the draw_id and the score given. Now i need to list to the user his votes received, so i need to check in the ratings table which users has voted on his draws, but i don't know how because the queries i've tried lists me only 1 record and i need all records.

Something like this:

5 stars | Draw Name | User

4 stars | Draw Name | User

This is th query i have until now, i achieved to show the most voted users but not this one.

```
SELECT u.usuario, u.id_usuario, d.id, COUNT(v.id) AS votos
FROM valoraciones v
JOIN dibujos d ON v.id_dibujo = d.id
JOIN usuarios u ON v.id_quien = u.id_usuario GROUP BY v.fecha ORDER BY votos DESC
```

This is driving me crazy.

Appreciate any help

Comment: You too drove me crazy by explaining schema with sentences and not SQL fiddle or Drawing here.

Comment: It's had to tell exactly what's wrong without having any data or such, but I would try by first removing GROUP BY to get a clue of what's going on.

Comment: @vnikhil ok, you're right, i'm gonna upload it to a fiddle, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/10b26/2

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld I tried removing the Group by and it only shows me 1 record.

Comment: Can you supply some data?

Comment: Yes of course, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b44fe/1 in that fiddle i have the demo data from the database, I think that now it's working but i need to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, some people here thinks is funny to downvote a post, well i'm posting the solution cause i know that it can be helpfull to.

This is the Query i built:

```
SELECT u.usuario, u.id_usuario, d.id, v.valoracion, v.fecha
FROM icar_valoraciones v
JOIN icar_dibujos d ON v.id_dibujo = d.id
JOIN icar_usuarios u ON v.id_quien = u.id_usuario WHERE d.id_quien = '{ID OF THE USER LOGGED IN}' GROUP BY v.id ORDER BY v.fecha DESC
```

You can find it here => http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b44fe/2